# How socket programming can be done in android?

Tags: android

HI i am new to android, i want to know how the socket programming can be done in android.Can any one help me by providing any tutorial links?

Thanks in advance
Shiva.M

Answer (score 3):

Android uses Java socket programming technologies. Here are a few links for you:

[Lesson: All About Sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

[Sockets Programming in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html)

Good luck!